# Android screen size resolution?

Tags: java, android

My app works perfectly in resolution 480x800. If I keep the 480x800 resolution but change the screen size to for example 2.7 inches, 3.7 inches or 5.4 inches it still is perfect. But when I change the resolution to for example 640x1066 all the ImageButtons is too small and in the wrong place in all screen sizes...

Comment: Can you add your layout file?

Answer (score 0):

This page shows you how to support different screen sizes with the following techniques:

Use view dimensions that allow the layout to resize
Create alternative UI layouts according to the screen configuration
Provide bitmaps that can stretch with the views

Visit this link https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes